# What part of man pages apply to the bash shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, manpages

I am currently using the bash shell but am a bit confused about man entries.  For example the man entry for source (`man source`):

```
DESCRIPTION
  sh
     The exec command specified by the arguments is  executed  in...

  csh
     exec executes command in place of the current  she...

  ksh
     With the exec built-in, if arg is give...
```

There are entries for several shells but not for the bash shell.  I know that bash stands for Bourne Again SHell so does this imply that the description for `sh` is the one that applies to bash?

Thanks

Comment: Recall that `sh` is the Bourne shell, and `bash` is the Bourne-again shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That man-page looks like it comes from a Unix (rather than Linux) system, like Solaris.

On Solaris, /bin/sh is the original Bourne shell, which lacks history, completion or the more advanced parameter substition that you'd find in ksh, POSIX and Bash shells. Also , command substitution can only be done with backticks, and not with $(*command*).

(Though if you have `/usr/xpg4/bin` earlier in your PATH, running 'sh' will get you the POSIX-compatible shell instead.)

As [profjim](https://superuser.com/users/28187/profjim) says, use `man bash` for details of Bash syntax.

Answer (score 1):

On many distros, sh is a link to bash, so yes running sh will give you bash, however it will be running in a restricted, sh-compatible mode. You can't rely on this without checking, though. sh might instead be a link to dash, or to its own binary.

For bash references, do [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). Also look at the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) and the 
[Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: ABS: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html Bash Manual: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html Also, a FAQ: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for help on a specific bash builtin, usually

```
help [builtin_name]
```

is what you want.